# Не работает SELECT CONCAT () AS ..... INTO OUTFILE '.....txt' FROM t.....;

Tags: c#, mysql, phpmyadmin

На локальной БД тестировал всё работало, купил хост и оказывается на нём не работает такой запрос SQL. Есть ли какой-то аналог этого запроса, чтобы пользователь базы мог скачать к себе таблицу из неё в .txt с использованием CONCAT (), разделители столбцов нужны определённые.

Comment: Почему вы думаете, что проблема с concat(), какое сообщение об ошибке получаете ? Я вот думаю что проблема с outfile, ибо mysql может писать файлы только на файловую систему машины где запущен сам

Comment: Да, это так. Просто всю команду сразу написал. Есть ли ещё способ, цель получить текстовик вот с таким содержимым из таблицы в таком вот виде:
00000000|word@word

Как я понял, данная команда бесполезна для сохранения таблицы на удалённый компьютер.

Comment: А как клиент к БД обращается ? Если на нем отдельная программа, которая это делает, то надо в ней явно писать чтение БД и запись в файл. Если же это веб-интерфейс то генерить на сервере текст этого файла и отдавать на клиента с content-type например application/bin что бы браузер его сразу записал